# linq get array elements query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to create an `array` of values only with elements of my `dictionary` which values is equal zero.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int notZeroValues = dict.Values.ToArray();  //sth here to get these elements efficiently
```

Please help?

Comment: is that a typo ? you mean values are **not** equal to zero?

Answer (score 2):

```
dict.Where(x => x.Value != 0).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Another way:

```
dict.Values.OfType<int>().Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();
```